# Transaction pool and Signed Extension Pre dispatch

Tags: transactions, weight, signed-extensions

My understanding is that when a transaction arrives it gets validated against all signed extensions. If the transaction is valid it then moves into the ready queue or future queue depending on the result, [ValidTransaction](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/transaction_validity/struct.ValidTransaction.html), after executing [validate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a200cdb93c6af5763b9c7bf313fa708764ac88ca/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs#L720).

Transactions that get put in the ready queue are gossiped and are used to build a block.

When building the block, the transaction runs all pre-dispatch functions. This [pre-dispatch](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/monthly-2021-09+1/sp_runtime/traits/trait.SignedExtension.html#method.pre_dispatch) function also re-validates the transaction before executing it.

Can you please explain the lifecycle after a transaction becomes invalid in pre-dispatch?

- Does it get put back in the future queue, verifying queue, or get dropped?

Comment: A transaction is only put in the future queue if it's requirements have not been fulfilled. Most likely the tx will get dropped as pre-dispatch is supposed to call validate at the time of extrinsic execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid transactions are dropped.  The only exception is if it is too large for the block and in that case is sent back to the verifying queue.  They are only placed in the Future queue if the nonce on the transaction is greater than the nonce on the account that sent it.